# ASP.NET Core 3 API Ignores Authorize Attribute with Bearertoken

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I´m working on a ASP.NET Core Web API. I´m using the newest version 3.0.0-preview4.19216.2.

I have the problem, that my API-Controller ignores the Authorize-Attribute but on another controller the Attribute works fine.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes =JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class SuppliersController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet("GetAll")]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            var companyId = int.Parse(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Company_Id").Value); // throws nullreference exception

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

But on another controller I have something similar but there the attribute works as expected

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetById(int id)
        {
            var test = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Company_Id").Value;
        }

    }
```

In the user controller works everything fine.

I also tried it in the SupplierController without the

> AuthenticationSchemes

but no different.

This is my AddAuthentication in the Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
                        var userId = int.Parse(context.Principal.Identity.Name);
                        var user = userService.GetById(userId);
                        if (user == null)
                        {
                            // return unauthorized if user no longer exists
                            context.Fail("Unauthorized");
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(context);

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
```

here is my complete startup.cs

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

            AuthenticationService.ConfigureSchoolProjectAuthentication(services, appSettingsSection);
            DependencyInjectionService.Inject(services);

            services.AddMvcCore()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

The strange thing is, when my SupplierController is called my authorization logic is not called (checked it with debugger) and when I call my UserController the logic is executed.

I think this is the reason why the claim is null. But why is the logic not called when the controller have a authorization attribute?

It´s seem like my authentication doesn't work entirely because I can access all my controller simply by using no authentication in Postman. What I´m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ok I found the anwser in this blog post [ASP.NET Core updates in .NET Core 3.0 Preview 4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-4/)

I have to change the order of my authentication registration from

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

to

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

So this solve my problem.

Comment: there is one issue left. you should switch:
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

because first it should Authenticate and then gets Authorized. Otherwise you get always an 401 because he cannot Authorize when there was no Authentication

Comment: @Vampirasu thx for the response. I will test it because at the moment everything works fine. But again thx for the hint!

Comment: @Vampirasu sorry for the late response. I correct the misstake. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that finds their way here and hasn't thought slightly outside the box, check the namespace of your [Authorize] attribute and check that it corresponds to your expected namespace. In my case it should have been:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
```

But actually I'd been lazy and used namespace autocomplete and it had applied an unrelated attribute (which still worked at both a class and method level) from HotChocolate's Namespace.

Look out for this!